# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) [This is a consistent help.]

Tags: javascript, php, html

I can't seem to get this to work. I've looked everywhere, I've tried many things. I'm desperate now.

Here are two different pieces of code that bring the same error.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function() { location.href = '<?php echo "/fetchorder.php?orderid=$_GET['orderid']"; ?>'; }, 3000);
    </script>
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=<?php echo "/fetchorder.php?orderid=$_GET['orderid']"; ?>" />
```

Any help or tips will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: is the error within `fetchorder.php`? Add the code from that php script

Comment: missing quote `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=<?...` in #2, `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url="<?...`

Comment: by the way putting this in a code snipit doesn't enhance the question at all.

Comment: Either put `{...}` around it or remote the quotes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26887807/989121

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes arround `orderid`.

Change your code to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function() { location.href = "<?php echo '/fetchorder.php?orderid='.$_GET['orderid']; ?>"; }, 3000);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php to print just the order ID

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function() { 
          location.href = '/fetchorder.php?orderid=<?php echo $_GET["orderid"]; ?>'; 
        }, 3000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first one

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() { location.href = '<?php echo "/fetchorder.php?orderid={$_GET['orderid']}"; ?>'; }, 3000);
</script>
```

OR ( this one being the preferred one )

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() { location.href = /fetchorder.php?orderid=<?php echo $_GET['orderid']; ?>'; }, 3000);
</script>
```

For the second one I don't think you need the url to refresh the current page

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" />
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp